# Control flow for R does not behave as expected with multiple if statements

Tags: r, control-flow

I have written the following function in R with two sequential if conditions:

```
f <- function(a) {
  if (a > 10) {
  c <- 'a is greater than 10'
  c
  }
  if (a < 10) {
  c <- 'a is less than 10'
  c 
  } 
}
```

Calling `f(1)` returns 'a is less than 10', however, calling `f(11)` returns **nothing**.

I am confused as to why this happens? The two sequential if statements should in theory have the same effect as an if-else statement, however, if the second condition is triggered instead of the first, **no output is returned**. I have tried multiple variations of this function, and the same effect is still observed. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: add print statements to variable c

Comment: I was not asking about how to get the right output, I was asking about why this behaviour occurrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R function returns anything that is returned by last call in this function (or by `return`).

In your example if `a < 10` then is returned `c` (as expected). But if condition `a < 10` is false, then last call is `if` condition - so nothing is returned.

You can try this to achieve your results:

```
f <- function(a) {
  if (a > 10) {
    c <- 'a is greater than 10'
    print(c)
  }
  if (a < 10) {
    c <- 'a is less than 10'
    print(c) 
  } 
}
f(1)
f(11)
```

Comment: Hi franiis, thanks for your reply. Does this mean that if conditions actually return something even if they are not triggered?

Comment: Great question. I checked it to be sure and yes. It returns `NULL`. You can use this to check it: `ff <- function() { return(if (1>2) {10})} ; a <- ff() ; a`